# How does Google App Engine Dev Server Stub the Datastore?

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine

GAE has a development server that you can use for imitating the "GAE cloud" in local, non-production environments. According to the docs, it mimics all Service API calls.

I'm curious as to how it works with respect to the NoSQL Datastore API. Is there a way to configure your GAE dev server to work with a local database (so you can feed it dummy data that is meaningful to your test cases)? If so how does this work as it is not documented anywhere that I can tell! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The development server uses a in-memory key-value store to simulate datastore locally. You can use the --use_sqlite flag to make it work with a local sqlite3 db file instead.

Local unit tests with datastore are documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Writing_Datastore_and_Memcache_Tests)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use --datastore_path flag to store data into file, not memory.